# How to host asp.net web application in Linux distro

Tags: asp.net, linux, apache, postgresql, iis

I have developed an intranet based web portal for my group of users in an office using asp.net 3.5. I tested it on my windows 7 machine by hosting the web application in my iis. But, it is not the permanent solution anyway! I have a linux server machine running 24x7 for various purposes. I have no other option to host my web application in that machine. Please guide me on this. FYI, I developed on asp.net 3.5 with postgresql as the database.

Comment: You're looking for [mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) but it's not exactly easy in most cases.

Comment: This is a bit more of a ServerFault question than a StackOverflow question

Answer (score 1):

1) Install VMWare

2) Create a Windows Server 200x VM.

3) Setup IIS to serve your app.

^This is sort of a joke but actually a valid answer.

Mono will run .NET code, but as far as serving web content I am not sure. I'd google around to see about how to server Mono backed code via something like apache.

http://www.mono-project.com/ASP.NET

Comment: Oh no it does. Some of the time. Sort of. When it wants to and you're not trying to use a library or feature that isn't supported yet.

Comment: VirtualBox could be used in Step 1 for free.